# Gephi not showing Nodes & Edges on graph

Tags: nodes, gephi, edges, network-analysis

It's been awhile since I've used Gephi, but I used to be pretty familiar with everything in v 0.8.xx.

I just loaded node & edge files into a brand-new installation of v0.9.0. They show up fine in the data lab & the context menu shows they exist. But nothing shows up on my graph & I can't figure out why.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

[image: My Gephi workspace]

Comment: I see a grey circle on the right of your *Graph* window. Could it be that your graph nodes are all mapped to the same coordinates? Try one of the `Layout` algorithms. Also the *forbidden* sign on the bottom right is sometimes not a good thing. It means that Gephi threw an exception of some sort that might not allow for the graph to be displayed. Last thing you can try is to open your graph file after you 've opened Gephi from the file menu

Comment: I came here having exactly the same problem. Then, I realized that there was some updates I didn't apply! In my case, they were indicated in the very bottom right corner (I realized after @Yannis comment). Just go to `Help -> Check for updates`, install what is found and restart Gephi. Hope it works for you.

Comment: Seems to be a bug, if the size is set too small you will never see them. I don't know if there is a way to set the size inside Gephi itself. See this discussion: https://github.com/gephi/gephi/issues/1447

Comment: How to set node size in 0.9.1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36239873/change-node-size-gephi-0-9-1

Answer (score 12):

There's a `Reset Windows` option in the `Windows` menu. That might work.

Failing that, either update Gephi or uninstall, re-install and start from scratch. It's tiresome, but it works. Most of the time.

Comment: Sometimes the 'graph' option in the 'windows'  menu works as well. It seems to be a bug, couldn't find a logical reason behind it!